# Are the Jagaroth from the Doctor Who story "City of Death" named after the Hindu god Jagannath?

Tags: doctor-who, hinduism

Is there any indication that the powerful race of warlike aliens, the Jagaroth, who are the villain(s) of the 1979 *Doctor Who* serial "[City of Death](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/City_of_Death_(TV_story))," are named after the god Jagannath?

[Jangannath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagannath) is a god worshipped in India, usually as a manifestation of the Hindu god Vishnu (although there are other syncretic aspects of Jagannath's liturgy, and Jangannath is also worshipped by some Buddhists and Jainists).  The name Jagannath means "lord of the universe," and it is one of the relatively small number of Hindu deities that is not typically represented in human or animal form.

In "City of Death," the Jagaroth's spaceship exploded on the primordial Earth, and the blast was responsible for creating the very first terrestrial life.  The single surviving Jagaroth is broken into pieces and scattered across time.  Ultimately, its goal is to create a time machine to go back billions of years and prevent the ship's destruction.  The Jagaroth race was portrayed as very powerful, and the whole story fits well with the Jagannath's non-human nature and the name meaning "lord of the universe."  So I was wondering if there was any confirmation that this was where *Doctor Who* creative staff (principally producer Graham Williams and script editor Douglas Adams, who wrote the story under the standard BBC pseudonym David Agnew) got the name for the evil aliens.